# My FBML APP doesn't work accessing through HTTPS

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, fbml

Just installed a SSL certificate and when I try to access to my fmbl app through https connection I can't see the application, the page is blank and I'm losing lots of users and the rate of my app is going to the deep down.

However, if I access to the app through http (non ssl) I can see without problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you open your app using Chrome Inspector or Firebug? Check the network activity and see what your app is returning. Is it giving a 403? What error messages come up? There should be something in response to your request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved?
'Cause i think the problem is arise by Chrome.
If your application has a self-signed SSL cert and you open it on chrome you'll receive a 501 error message. Chrome should show an alert message whit a 'continue' button to enter the app, but this doesn't happen when chrome call an https resource from an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a self-signed certificate? For some reason, FB doesn't support those, and you'll need a certificate which is signed by a CA.